# Powershell change ad field based on CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, powershell-2.0

Have a CSV formatted as

```
User     Department
myname   test1
yourname test1
```

Have script:

```
$data = import-csv c:\ad.csv
$data |% { 
set-qaduser $_.$User -department $_.department
}
```

Import works fine but I cant get the field change, keep getting error:

```
Set-QADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:12
```

Can any one steer me in right direction?

Comment: The $User in $_.$User looks suspicious.  Any chance that should be $_.User ?

Comment: Possibly. As I want to do this by username (logon name) would the column title and data in that column need to be username based?

Comment: The property names will be the column headings.  Try it with just $_.user and see if that doesn't work better.

Comment: so if I want to use logonname I need to change column header to logononame then. Will give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: No, he is saying that there is a second $ in $_.$user which is not something we are used to seeing under normal circumstances. It really looks like the issue is $_.user vs $_.$user (as it is in your script above).

Comment: Mjolinor add you answer and I will mark is as you got there first. Thanks every one for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra character around `$_.$User`. It should be `$_.User` instead.

```
$data = import-csv c:\ad.csv;
$data |% { 
    Set-QADUser -Identity $_.User -Department $_.department;
}
```